# Deserialize SOAP Body generated by AXIS2

Tags: java, xml, soap, deserialization, apache-axis

I am currently logging the XML generated by AXIS2 client code in my DB. Now i need to resend that XML request from the log.
I have the XML Content that will come inside "SOAPBody" tag.

I have tried to using BeanUtil deserialize method. and even Axis2 object.factory.parse method, both do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following. If anyone looking to get he raw xml string from Axis2, you can use the following code.

```
    OMElement  ele= someElementObject.getOMElement(SomeElementObject.MY_QNAME, OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory());

    String xmlString= ele.toStringWithConsume();
```

where someElementObject is the xml tag pojo generated by Axis2 wsdl import wizard.

To parse a string xml to Axis2 object, use the following code.

```
SomeElementObject obj=SomeElementObject.Factory.parse(SOME_XML_STREAM);
```